# How to get the exception object after asserting?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

For example, I have the following code in my unit test.

```
Action act = () => subject.Foo2("Hello");

act.Should().Throw<InvalidOperationException>()
```

After the assertion, I want to run a couple more steps of processing on the thrown exception and assert on the outcome of processing. for example:

```
 new ExceptionToHttpResponseMapper()
   .Map(thrownException)
   .HttpStatusCode.Should().Be(Http.Forbidden);
```

I can write a try-catch like,

```
var thrownException;
    try
    {
    subject.Foo2("Hello");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    thrownException = e;
    }

    // Assert
```

but I was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Have a quick look at the docs here https://fluentassertions.com/exceptions/

Comment: The `And` and `Which` seem to provide access to the thrown exception.

Comment: What type does the map return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few options based on the documentation provided here

https://fluentassertions.com/exceptions/

The `And` and `Which` seem to provide access to the thrown exception.

And there is also a `Where` function to apply an expression on the exception.

```
act.Should().Throw<InvalidOperationException>()
    .Where(thrownException => HasCorrectHttpResponseMapping(thrownException));
```

With `HasCorrectHttpResponseMapping` being

```
bool HasCorrectHttpResponseMapping(InvalidOperationException thrownException)
{
    var httpResponse = new ExceptionToHttpResponseMapper().Map(thrownException);
    return httpResponse.HttpStatusCode == Http.Forbidden;
}
```

Comment: Where() would suffice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all your assertions in a `using _ = new AssertionScope()`

Comment: [AssertionScope](https://fluentassertions.com/introduction#assertion-scopes) is for batching multiple assertions, so a failed test result would show errors from all the assertions instead of the first failed assertion. Can you elaborate in context of the OP?